# Stripes in background in RDL

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

Is it possible to add stripes in the textbox in report?

So the result looks like in the picture?
[image: stripes in background]

User chooses color for the column in the application
[color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWIkA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no built in way of doing this (no fill style) but you could use an image of the stripes as a background image. You would need to create and save images for each colour and style and add them as embedded images in the report.

You can then set the background image of a textbox to the required image.

[image]

...  or better still use an expression to select the image based on conditions.

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!ItemCode.Value >10 , "RedStripe",
Fields!ItemCode.Value >50 , "GreenStripe",
True, Nothing
)
```

Where `Redstripe` and `GreenStripe` are the image names you embedded.

You can set the image to repeat etc from the properties panel

[image]

---

**Update after OP stated that colour is parameterised.**

---

If the colour is a parameter then we need a slightly different approach.

First you need to create an image with stripes (any colour will do ), and then remove the stripe pixels so that the stipes are now transparent. Save this as a PNG.

I created one quickly whist testing which you can save from here hopefully. You'll just have to move the mouse around in the area below as it's a white on white image! Or switch StackOverflow to the dark theme, then you can right-click and save the image. If not you'll just have to create one yourself.

Image below here.. switch StackOverflow to Dark theme to see it

[image]

Image above here..

Now you will need to set the background image to this image **but also** set the `backgroundcolor` property to an expression. In this exmaple, I set the background to the value of my parameter.

My parameter is just text and I typed in some hex values in the form `#FFFFFF`. You will have to work out how to get the value from your color pickers to the report yourself, ask a new question if required.

Here's the report design

[image]

and here is the report running using a few sample hex values.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Alan. However, user can choose color from the pallette and expects to see stripes with the same color, so I should find a way to display this without knowing which color will be used.

Comment: No problem. If this answered you question, please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left under the vote up/down buttons). This helps other users find answers to similar questions.

Comment: How do they choose a colour? From a parameter? Edit your question to add this info as that was not part of your original question.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the my question: user picks a color from the color pallete (shown in a picture).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! However, stripes can not be seen in Word in Excel, it works nice in PDF.

Comment: Does anyone has any idea how to mak this option work when export in Word and Excel?

Comment: you will need to ask a new question. Not sure if background images are supported in all renderers.